# verify maven managed dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, configuration-management

maven allows you to define in pom file:

(A) `dependencies` -> the actual direct dependencies of the project

(B) `dependencyManagement`/`dependencies` -> managed dependencies that affect dependencies of category (A) with undefined version and transitive dependencies.

- If I put wrong/unknown artifact on category A - maven will surely fail.
- If I put wrong/unknown artifact on category B - maven will fail only if it affects category A (for instance, A defines dep on `foo:bar` and B defines dep on `foo:bar:<unknown-version>`.

---

I wonder if there is any existing plugin that will allow me to verify all managed deps (category B) - make sure they actually exist.

I have 1 global pom project with deps management that serves multiple projects and I want to verify any change to the deps in the CI before uploading new version to remote repository

Comment: Your assumption you made is wrong, cause the dependencies tag is not inside the `build` tag. They are keep on their own. http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies. If you check the global pom the define deps using a real pom which uses the real depenencies locally that's the test..I hope you don't upload the deps manually into remote repository...

Comment: @khmarbaise It would still be great to have a check whether dependencyManagement entries actually exist, without constructing and updating a test project.

Comment: Might be an idea for an improvement of plugins ...might be located in the maven-dependency-plugin goal like `resolve-dependency-management` something like this? Someone can make a jira request for it?...

Comment: @khamrbaise - you're right. I was confused. But the question still valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maven dependency plugin there is goal `dependency:analyze-dep-mgt`. You may use it to check dependencies in `dependencyManagement` section of your `pom.xml`.
If you need deeper control or more functionality, options would be to create your own plugin or have a dummy project which would use all your managed dependencies (although I should say this is a cumbersome solution).